# Installing WordPress directly in HTTPS (SSL is already installed)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, installation

My question is very simple, I think, but very common. For days, I was searching the solution but find nothing at all.

I'm trying to install WordPress directly in HTTPS on this URL: https://viktora.org
As you can see the CSS styles is gone and not working properly. I'm using Apache with NGINX proxy server on my Debian 9 OS.

I tried all the solution like setting the .htaccess file, adding: define('WP_HOME','https://viktora.org');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://viktora.org');
in wp_config.php file but it didn't help me.

Please, help me with the right solution. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell WordPress that it's behind a proxy otherwise it may not actually rewrite the locations correctly. Adding a check to your `wp-config.php` file like this may fix this for you.

```
// If we're behind a proxy server and using HTTPS, we need to alert Wordpress of that fact
// see also http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL#Using_a_Reverse_Proxy
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https') {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

It's a new installation. I don't have wp-config yet. I have an only wp-config-sample.php file. Do I need to create new one?

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't help: https://viktora.org/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1

Now, wp-config.php is created, but I still see missing CSS and HTTPS errors.

Do you have other advice?

Comment: I see these errors in the console: https://prnt.sc/raicli
hope will help to understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: @ViktorAvramenko sorry at this point I am out of ideas since it looks like you already tried to setup the `defines` for site and home with `https` urls :(. It does seem as though WP is not outputting the correct urls you need but I do not see why since it is a fresh install with the defines used to point to the url you wanted. Sorry I was not able to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the site url in admin dashboard too in advance of the above mentioned one. Upon opening the url "https://viktora.org", it seems that you need add DBname, username and password

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it's not useful.

As I said, IT'S A NEW INSTALLATION and I don't have a Dashboard of WordPress jet. 

I just uploaded the WP files into the server, and right now, as you can see, before proceeding, I need to resolve problems with HTTPS and CSS that is missing right now.

I see that WordPress required to insert database connection, but I won't do this because before I need to solve the problem with the visualization, see the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/raakr2

I'm sure I need to specify some configuration in WP files, for this, I'm searching for help.